# how to make dynamic conditions in operators in if conditions

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I have to make filters in which every condition is dynamic like greater than, less than equal to with `&&` and `||` operator for that I have made below code

```
    <?php
    $a = 5;
    $b = 2;
    $grater = '<';
    $equal = '==';
    $and = '&&';
    
    if(($a .$equal. $b)){
        echo 'hii';
    }else{
        echo 'hello';
    }
?>
```

but when I use this code it is not working properly. can anybody help me in this

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [match expression](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php) like this:

```
function compute($operator, $a, $b)
{
    return match ($operator) {
        '<'  => ($a <  $b),
        '==' => ($a == $b),
        '&&' => ($a && $b),
    };
}

var_dump(compute('==', 5, 2));
```

This has three advantages:

1. You avoid the use of `eval()`.
2. It will also work with strings.
3. It is easy to expand to other operators.

Comment: I have tried this also with this code "if(eval(($column .$filter. $val) .$operator. ($column3 .$filter3. $val3) )){return true;}" but it is not consider as a condition and giving this error "syntax error, unexpected 'PEN' (T_STRING)"

Comment: @Mohini Sorry, I do not understand your comment. Why add the code and the error seems completely unrelated.

Comment: I have use `if(eval(($column .$filter. $val) .$operator. ($column3 .$filter3. $val3) )){return true;}` this conditon and it is giving me  this error

Answer (score 1):

if you concate strings into condition, this will result to string, so you will not get
`if(5 == 2)`
but you will get
`if("5 == 2")`
and this will be always true, because php will evaluate any non empty string as true. You need to eval this string, for example:
`if(eval($a . $equal . $b))`
but using eval is bad practise
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: @silentwasd  when I use this eval() it is giving me "syntax error, unexpected 'PEN' (T_STRING)" Error

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `eval`, as other answers suggested. If you choose this path, note that you will need to protect against [PHP injection](https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/php-security-2/), which is, by itself a very complex topic. You will need to validate both the operands and the operators. While that's possible and, assuming it's properly validated it would be safe as well, it is an unclean, hacky solution and you will always have to worry about PHP code injection, whenever you change the code, you will need to change the validator as well, with danger always looming around.

As a result, I propose the implementation of functions, such as:

```
function equal($a, $b, $strict = false) {
    return $strict ? ($a === $b) : ($a == $b);
}
```

and then you can do something of the like:

```
if (equal($a, $b)) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```php
if (eval("($a . $equal . $b)"))
```

Comment: _**Important:**_ Only do this if you are 100% in control of all the values in those variables. If it's user input, or that those variables come from some other external source/source that can be manipulated by someone else, don't use `eval()` on them since that would allow people to run arbitrary pieces of PHP code on your server.